# Synthesizing a lambda in Roslyn's C# compiler

Tags: c#, roslyn

I've been experimenting with the recently open-sourced C# compiler in Roslyn, seeing if I can add language features.

I'm now trying to add some syntax sugar, a new prefix operator that is basically shorthand for a certain pattern. For now I'm piggy-backing on the pre-existing `&` "address of", outside of `unsafe` contexts.

The pattern I want to expand is as follows: `&n` is equivalent to:

```
Property.Bind(v => n = v, () => n)
```

The method `Property.Bind` is assumed to be available in a library, with the signature:

```
public static IProperty<T> Bind<T>(Action<T> set, Func<T> get)
```

So in essence I need to synthesize two lambdas:

1. binds to `n` as an lvalue and does an assignment to it from its parameter, and
2. has no parameters and evaluates `n`. I then need to make an invocation to `Property.Bind` passing those two lambdas as the parameters.

[My previous experiments](http://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/tag/roslyn/) have been much easier than this because they were able to piggy back on easy-to-find existing features, so there was practically zero work to do!

But this time I'm struggling to find anything similar to what I'm doing here. So far I've been stepping through how a `BoundLambda` is built by the compiler from the source, and it's unfolding into a big ol' mess. I was modifying `BindAddressOfExpression` in `Binder_Operators.cs`, making it start with an extra `if` statement for safe contexts:

```
private BoundExpression BindAddressOfExpression(PrefixUnaryExpressionSyntax node, DiagnosticBag diagnostics)
{
    if (!this.InUnsafeRegion)
    {
        BoundExpression rValue = BindValue(node.Operand, diagnostics, BindValueKind.RValue);
        BoundExpression lValue = BindValue(node.Operand, diagnostics, BindValueKind.Assignment);

        var valueParamSymbol = new SourceSimpleParameterSymbol(null, rValue.Type, 0, RefKind.None, "__v", ImmutableArray<Location>.Empty);
        var valueParam = new BoundParameter(node, valueParamSymbol);
        var assignment = new BoundAssignmentOperator(node, lValue, valueParam, RefKind.None, rValue.Type);

        var assignmentStatement = new BoundExpressionStatement(node, assignment);
        var assignmentBlock = new BoundBlock(node, ImmutableArray<LocalSymbol>.Empty, ImmutableArray.Create<BoundStatement>(assignmentStatement)) { WasCompilerGenerated = true };
        assignmentBlock = FlowAnalysisPass.AppendImplicitReturn(assignmentBlock);
```

So (presumably!) now I have the assignment block for the first lambda, but getting a complete `BoundLambda` around it looks to be a whole new challenge.

I'm wondering: is there a way to "cheat" for this kind of syntactic sugar, by asking the parser/binder to work on a string of C#, as if it had appeared in place of the actual code? That way, manually constructing all the parts and stitching them together won't be necessary. After all, the existing compiler is ideally suited for this!

Comment: Having this only work in safe regions seems like it would violate the principle of least surprise.  `&p` isn't meaningful where `p` is a property access expression, anyway, so why not trigger from that?

Comment: Also, you might go for `Property.Bind(delegate(T v) { n = v; }, delegate () { return n; })` and skip the lambdas.

Comment: I'm only borrowing `&` to experiment. If I can get it working I plan to define a new operator `%` to mimic C++/CLI and C++/CX.

Comment: @BenVoigt - would using delegate make it any easier to build the `BoundExpression`?

Comment: I really have no idea.  But the older features usually are simpler.

Comment: @BenVoigt - sadly not in this case; lambdas and anonymous methods are handled by the same method, `BindAnonymousFunction` in `Binder_Expressions.cs`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Roslyn, but languages with metaprogramming support or compiler frameworks usually have some notion of quasi-quoting and splicing, i.e. allow you to quote a piece of code and splice external code elements into it, rather than write it all by yourself as a series of code elements. Roslyn might be too young to support this, though.

Comment: @Avish - that's what I'm hoping for. The problem is that I previously tried building a phony `SyntaxNode` tree (for a simpler feature) at the parsing stage, and the IDE blew up complaining about inconsistency. When I switched to building `BoundExpression` trees instead, it was fine. The problem is, at the Binder level it seems to be all quite manual unless you're doing something that is already done by more than one other existing language feature (in which case you'll find a nice helper method ready for you to use!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATED**: I've settled on a new class called `SyntaxTemplate`, which is immutable and so can be created statically and reused. e.g.

```
private static readonly SyntaxTemplate _pointerIndirectionTemplate 
      = new SyntaxTemplate("p.Value");

private static readonly SyntaxTemplate _propertyReferenceTemplate
     = new SyntaxTemplate("System.Property.Bind(__v_pr__ => o = __v_pr__, () => o)");

private static readonly SyntaxTemplate _propertyReferenceTypeTemplate 
     = new SyntaxTemplate("System.IProperty<T>");

private static readonly SyntaxTemplate _enumerableTypeTemplate 
     = new SyntaxTemplate("System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>");
```

It internally has an immutable dictionary of all the identifiers, so any can be replaced by name, e.g. for an expression:

```
if (!operand.Type.IsPointerType())
    return BindExpression(
        _pointerIndirectionTemplate.Replace("p", node.Operand).Syntax, 
        diagnostics);
```

Or for a type:

```
if (this.IsIndirectlyInIterator || !this.InUnsafeRegion)
    return BindNamespaceOrTypeOrAliasSymbol(
        _enumerableTypeTemplate.Replace("T", node.ElementType).Syntax,
        diagnostics, basesBeingResolved, suppressUseSiteDiagnostics);
```

`SyntaxTemplate` looks like this:

```
internal class SyntaxTemplate
{
    public ExpressionSyntax Syntax { get; private set; }

    private readonly ImmutableDictionary<string, ImmutableList<IdentifierNameSyntax>> _identifiers;

    public SyntaxTemplate(string source)
    {
        Syntax = SyntaxFactory.ParseExpression(source);

        var identifiers = ImmutableDictionary<string, ImmutableList<IdentifierNameSyntax>.Builder>.Empty.ToBuilder();

        foreach (var node in Syntax.DescendantNodes().OfType<IdentifierNameSyntax>())
        {
            ImmutableList<IdentifierNameSyntax>.Builder list;
            if (!identifiers.TryGetValue(node.Identifier.Text, out list))
                list = identifiers[node.Identifier.Text] = 
                    ImmutableList<IdentifierNameSyntax>.Empty.ToBuilder();
            list.Add(node);
        }

        _identifiers = identifiers.ToImmutableDictionary(
            p => p.Key, p => p.Value.ToImmutableList());
    }

    private SyntaxTemplate(ExpressionSyntax syntax,
        ImmutableDictionary<string, ImmutableList<IdentifierNameSyntax>> identifiers)
    {
        Syntax = syntax;
        _identifiers = identifiers;
    }

    public SyntaxTemplate Replace(string identifier, SyntaxNode value)
    {
        return new SyntaxTemplate(
            Syntax.ReplaceNodes(_identifiers[identifier], (o1, o2) => value),
            _identifiers.Remove(identifier));
    }
}
```

Because the replacement value is a `SyntaxNode`, you can use the node already created by the parser, so there is no wasted effort reparsing the same syntax twice.

**YET MORE**: This works-ish except that if there are errors in the user's source (e.g. they use the new syntax in a situation where it makes no sense) then the errors generated during binding refer to locations in the template source, which are meaningless in the user's source. So the IDE cannot display red squiggles, etc.

To get around this, you can use a helper method that captures the diagnostics in a temporary bag, and then replays them into the real bag with the location changed to the place in the user's source where your syntax was used:

```
private T RedirectDiagnostics<T>(DiagnosticBag diagnostics, CSharpSyntaxNode nodeWithLocation, Func<DiagnosticBag, T> generate)
{
    var captured = new DiagnosticBag();
    var result = generate(captured);

    foreach (var diag in captured.AsEnumerable().OfType<DiagnosticWithInfo>())
        diagnostics.Add(new CSDiagnostic(diag.Info, nodeWithLocation.Location));

    return result;
}
```

Example usage, just wrapping the first example from above:

```
if (!operand.Type.IsPointerType())
    return RedirectDiagnostics(diagnostics, node, redirected => 
        BindExpression(_pointerIndirectionTemplate.Replace("p", node.Operand).Syntax, redirected));
```

Now the red squiggles work properly (and in a true compilation, the line numbers on the error messages are correct).

Comment: I would at least add some parentheses around the substitutions, and possible put a placeholder which can be replaced in the resulting AST.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, I'm considering defining a special syntax in the language for a placeholder. I could use that instead of `{0}`, and that would save double-parsing the operand(s). Maybe even exposing this as a meta-programming feature, so extensions like this can be declared in user source. In what situations would the parentheses be needed?

Comment: If `v => {0} = v` is treated as text, then any precedence of the lambda operator `=>` and the assignment operator `=` will be compared to any operators that appear inside `{0}`.  For example, `x |= y = v` is parsed as `x |= (y = v)`

Comment: Ah. I had a theory that the user of `&` would need to add parentheses themselves for anything complex, but if that's not true then you're right. But hopefully if I can get the placeholder alternative working then that would avoid this problem altogether.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't want to bet that parentheses are preserved by the process of parsing and then `Operand.GetText()`

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you look at how query expressions "expand" into method calls with compiler-generated lambdas.

Comment: +1 Not sure why you got a downvote for that so I've balanced it out.  A perfectly good suggestion and I did start off down that investigation path before I got really lazy.